# Detect movement direction of container elevator arm with contacless sensors generating signal for GPS/Modem

Tags: sensor, signal, movement

Container Washer Truck: So I want to  generate a brief signal "Analog In" 24V for my GPS/Modem to send to backend once (with GeoLoc and Timestamp) when the elevator arm moves UP and passes contacless sensor A first, then contactless sensor B. No signal when it moves down past B and then past A. When the arm moves down again past B first and then past A no signal is generated. After going past A downwards process needs to be at original situation again.  What's a simple most robust way? Microcontroller or relay fine, which? 24V vehicle, 2D movement only, can be three sensors,too but contactless. (No budget for RFID tags etc.)

Comment: Microcontroller definitely the way to go. Inductive sensor or Hall effect sensor with a magnet (probably the cheapest & most robust). Optical might get dirty and accelerometer probably won't work well as vibrations.

Comment: Given the industrial situation I'd say PLC or relays, unless you can ruggedize a microcontroller to survive. If you already have a PLC use that, otherwise a couple of relay should do the job.

Comment: PLC is maybe a better idea indeed

Answer (score 1):

> So I want to generate a brief signal "Analog In" 24V for my GPS/Modem ...

I think you want a **digital** on-off for this, not analog.

> ... signal ... when the elevator arm moves UP and passes contacless sensor A first, then contactless sensor B. No signal when it moves down past B and then past A. When the arm moves down again past B first and then past A no signal is generated. After going past A downwards process needs to be at original situation again.

*Timing diagram.*

```
            <- up --->   <- down -->               <- up ---> 
               _                  _                 _
Sensor A   ___| |________________| |______ _ _ ____| |______
                   _       _                             _
Sensor B   _______| |_____| |_____________ _ _ _________| |_
               ____               ________ _ _ __________
RLY1       ___|    |_____________|                       |__
                   _                                     _
RLY2/Output ______| |_____________________ _ _ _________| |_
```

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHmFkN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Relay logic.*

How it works:

- When SW-A is activated RLY1 will pick up and remain on via its own contact after the arm continues past it in the upward direction. This "arms" the circuit for SW-B.
- When SW-B is activated RLY2 will pick up and latch on via its own contact.
- Power to RLY1 will be immediately cut. D1 should slow down RLY1 dropping out for long enough that RLY2 can be fully energised and latch.
- When the arm passes B RLY2 will drop out.
- On the way back down RLY2 can't energise again as RLY1 is no longer energised.

Note that RLY1 will energise again and latch on the way back down. This should still be OK  for your requirements as RLY2 won't be pulsed until you go back up to B again.

Other than this I would recommend a micro PLC such as Siemens LOGO!, or equivelant from A-B, Mitsubishi, etc. Inductive proximity switches will be most robust for the sensing.

Comment: Thanks. The backend people want the signal on AIN1 but it will be used "digitally" <5V and >20V.

Comment: If you've got a PLC or controller then why aren't you doing the logic in there?